# How to check if the keyword returned value is true or false in Robotic Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I'm new to Robot Framework scripting. I am facing an hurdle with this line.

So as per the Image horizon library, the keyword 'does exist' returns TRUE or FALSE

But how do I check if this keyword returns true or false

Answer (score 1):

`Run Keyword and Return Status` this keyword returns the status of True or False.
Here is the official documentation for the same.
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status

If you are looking for an example line, then here it is:

```
${IS_PRESENT}    Run Keyword and Return Status    Element Should Contain    something that I am asserting for
Log to Console    ${IS_PRESENT}    # returns the status True/False on to the console
# Log    ${IS_PRESENT}      # prints the status True/False in the log.html file
```